# Approach to or without to

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I have been taking a look at the verb *approach*, which is a verb that I find very interesting, containing many different meanings, and one from which works in many different ways. However, when talking about the verb *approach* that means something moving nearer something/one: *I was able to hear the sirenes of the ambulance approaching to the local*. Must "*to*" be proceeded after "approach" when it implies to say something moving nearer or getting closer to someone/thing? Is this how it was supposed to be: *I was able to hear the sirenes of the ambulance approaching the local* or otherwise?

Also, check these examples out: *As I walked down the hill two thieves came out of an alley and approached to me*

Or

*As I walked down the hill two thieves came out of an alley and approached me*.

*I can hear an airplane approaching us*

Or

*I can hear an airplane approaching to us* ?

Comment: You might also look at the noun *approach*. For example "The airplane is on (the) approach *to the runway*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition *to* is not necessary, since *approaching* implies moving *towards* *something/someone* unlike *going/coming* which may need additional context "*going/coming to*"

You might use a presposition if the perspective is different

> The ambulance was approaching *from* the main entrance of the hospital.
>   *the ambulance was coming from the main entrance*
>
> The ambulance was approaching the hospital.
>   *the ambulance was going to the hospital*

In your other examples

> As I walked down the hill two thieves came out of an alley and approached <s>to</s> me
>   *As I walked down the hill two thieves came out of an alley and came to me*
>
> I can hear an airplane approaching <s>to</s> us
>   I can hear an airplane coming to us

Comment: So, if I said: The ambulance was approaching from the main entrance of the hospital to the parking lot. Would 'to' be necessary in this sentence?

Comment: No, you don't need to use "*to*", "The ambulance was *approaching* the parking lot *from* the main entrance", "I was standing in the parking lot when the ambulance approached from the main entrance", both convey that the ambulance was moving from the main entrance to the parking lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Michael Swan in his Practical English Usage*, no preposition is used after **approach**. E.g.

The train is now ***approaching London*** Paddington. (NOT ... *approaching to* ...)